# iPhone: How do I create a simple Done button?

Tags: iphone

Newbie alert!  I have a simple calculator with 4 text input fields.  When I tap into a field the number pad appears and I enter numbers.  No problems so far.  Now, when testing this using the simulator I press return on the keyboard and using TextFieldShouldReturn my fields perform their calculations perfectly and the number keypad disappears nicely.  The problem is, the number keypad does not have a 'Done' key so if I place a button let's say on the toolbar how do I code it to perform the action of the Return key?

Answer (score 1):

[How do you dismiss the keyboard when editing a UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274319/how-do-you-dismiss-the-keyboard-when-editing-a-uitextfield)

I asked the same question. :-)

the answer is that you set the delegate for the UITextField to your controller and impliment this method.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
```

---

In response to your clarification

```
- (void)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender {
  [_textField resignFirstResponder];
  [self performCalculations];
}
```

You'll have to move all your calculations into the `performCalculatinos` method and make sure you have a variable that points to the UITextField.

Comment: I tried that already.  Actually I saw your post.  The problem is not with the keyboard disappearing.  The keyboard disappears just fine cause I have placed a Done action in my .h file and then written the action in .m as:

- (IBAction)done:(id)sender {
 [textfield1 resignFirstResponder];
 [textfield2 resignFirstResponder];
 [textfield3 resignFirstResponder];
 [textfield4 resignFirstResponder];
 
}

So this is called when I click/press the Done button on my toolbar but how do I now get the same behaviour as the Return key being pressed or the Done key being tapped on the normal iPhone keyboard?

Comment: I added to my answer, I hope that helped.