# UITextView not remove keyboard

Tags: iphone, iphone-softkeyboard

Question, I have a `UITextView` in one of my views, but when the user hits the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, the keyboard is removed.  I really want the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to put in a `\n`.  This happens in several other places in my app.

Lots of posts to have the return remove the keyboard, but nothing how to keep it.

In the IB, I have the return key type set to Default.  Any other settings I need to check into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither `UITextView` nor `UITextField` won't remove the keyboard by default. For `UITextView` that's because the user may really want to enter a line-break. If you want to remove the keyboard you need to write code.

See:

- [How to dismiss keyboard for UITextView with return key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703754/how-to-dismiss-keyboard-for-uitextview-with-return-key)
- [How do you dismiss the keyboard when editing a UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274319/how-do-you-dismiss-the-keyboard-when-editing-a-uitextfield)

Comment: Thanks, but I am wanting the opposite to happen.  The return key is removing the keyboard, and I want it to put in a new line.

Comment: @Rob: but that's the default behavior! Can you show us some of your code?

Comment: Kenny, you are correct, and in looking for the code I found where I was removing the keyboard.  This returned the form to the default behavior.  Thanks for the response, it did send me back into the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
  // end editing and thus hide keyboard
  [textView resignFirstResponder];
  return YES;
}
```