# How to make the keyboard go away?

Tags: iphone, keyboard, iphone-softkeyboard

I added a text field, and when I tap in there, the keyboard slides up. What are the steps needed that the keyboard shows an "OK" which actually really works? I mean...hitting "OK" or "Return" does exactly nothing.

Is there some sort of KeyboardDelegateProtocol where I must do some weird stuff like

```
-(BOOL)shouldReallyGoAway {
    return YES;//of course!
}
```

Is there an 200 pages keyboard programming guide to read? Couldn't find one...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you dismiss the keyboard when editing a UITextField](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274319/how-do-you-dismiss-the-keyboard-when-editing-a-uitextfield)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/741185/easy-way-to-dismiss-keyboard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to handle the tap on the 'OK' button (`Did End On Exit` event) and resign the first responder status for the text field.

```
- (IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender {
[sender resignFirstResponder];
```

}

You might want to handle few other actions - like the background tap. You'll need an invisible button that will cover your background and trap the taps and an IBOutlet for your text field (since your `sender` will be the button, not the text field)

Answer (score 2):

No reason for a 200 pages guide, it's right there in the introduction of the UITextField which you propably use.

Use

```
[aTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

to make the keyboard go away programmatically.

Also, there is the UITextFieldDelegate with appropriate methods regarding Return, which you might use, i.e. `-textFieldShouldReturn:`.

e.g.

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```