# How to dissmiss keybord when editing UITextField

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you dismiss the keyboard when editing a UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274319/how-do-you-dismiss-the-keyboard-when-editing-a-uitextfield)

I know that I need to tell my UITextField to resign first responder when I want to dismis the keyboard, but I'm not sure how to know when the user has pressed the "Done" key on the keyboard. Is there a notification I can watch for?

Comment: Why the downvote? The question's valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the delegate of the UITextFieldDelegate ViewController(.h file) class and impliment following  method in viewController (.m file) class.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return NO;
}
```

It will work..

Answer (score 2):

You should implement this method to know if the user has just pressed the *return key* (that key is called *"return key"*), and don't forget to *return YES* from this method.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField {
```

Comment: Make sure you set your viewcontroller (or whatever is retaining on your text field) as the delegate of the text field, or you won't receive this message.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a delegate on your `UITextField` : [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html)

Then this method is there for you :

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement next methods in your UITextFieldDelegate class:

*Tells the delegate that editing stopped for the specified text field.*

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
```

*Asks the delegate if the text field should process the pressing of the return button.*

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField;
```