# UIScrollView dismisskeyboard not working

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield

I have a textfield on `UIScrollview`.

When the user taps outside of `UITextfield`, I use `UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive` to dismiss the keyboard. But it is not dismissing the keyboard.

What is wrong with my code?

```
m_scrollProfile = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)];
m_scrollProfile.backgroundColor = kBGWhiteColor;
m_scrollProfile.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self.m_bgImageView addSubview:m_scrollProfile];

m_scrollProfile.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive;
```

Comment: This question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274319/how-do-you-dismiss-the-keyboard-when-editing-a-uitextfield

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue recently. In my header, I added `<UITextFieldDelegate>` as follows:

```
@interface YourClass : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

I added this in my `viewDidLoad`:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

and

```
self.myTextField.delegate = self;
```

and this method down below:

```
- (void)dismissKeyboard:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    NSLog(@"Dismiss keyboard");
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Not sure what else is going on w/ your implementation, but it works in the app I'm currently working on when the user clicks outside the `UITextField`.

Comment: tapgesture is working fine...but i am asking why interactive dismissmode is not working?